# How to change value of column with different percentage values depending on the categories of other column

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a data frame as:

```
df

cat   income 
1     10
2     20
2     50
3     60
1     20
```

I want to apply a fixed percentage increase category wise as per the scheme:

```
If the cat==1-----> income * 1.1 (10% increase)  
If the cat==2-----> income * 1.2 (20% increase)  
If the cat==3-----> income * 1.3 (30% increase)
```

Then i need to append the increased column to the above data frame as below:

```
df

cat   income increased_income
1     10      11
2     20      24
2     50      60
3     60      78
1     20      22
```

How can i achieve the above using pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
cat_map={1:1.1, 2:1.2, 3:1.3}

df["increased_income"]=df["income"].mul(df["cat"].map(cat_map))
```

Outputs:

```py
   cat  income  increased_income
0    1      10              11.0
1    2      20              24.0
2    2      50              60.0
3    3      60              78.0
4    1      20              22.0
```

Answer (score 1):

First we create factors of your `cat` by dividing it by `10` and adding `1`. Then we multiple these factors with your `income`

```
df['increased_income'] = df['income'].mul(df['cat'].div(10).add(1))
# or with basic Python operators
# df['increased_income'] = df['income'] * (df['cat'] / 10 + 1)

   cat  income  increased_income
0    1      10              11.0
1    2      20              24.0
2    2      50              60.0
3    3      60              78.0
4    1      20              22.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Condition using boolean select

```
a=df['cat']==1
b=df['cat']==2
c=df['cat']==3
```

Apply np.where

```
df['increased_income']=np.where(a,(df['income']*1.1),(np.where(b,(df['income']*1.2),(np.where(c,(df['income']*1.3),df['income'])))))
df
```

Outcome

[image]